# Excel Data List Validation in Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, validation

I have a range named "STATE".
I want to set data validation in range ("A1") to only take value within this range using Powershell.

Below is what I have tried. Does not work. I dont know what to put as 4th and 5th parameters. The first 3 are Excel constants equivalent to xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop and xlBetween respectively.

```
$ws.Range("A1").Validation.Add(3, 1, 1, "=STATE", 0)
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer after trial and error.

```
$missing = [system.type]::missing
$ws.Range("A1").Validation.Delete()
$ws.Range("A1").Validation.Add(3, 1, $missing, "=STATE", $missing)
```

A1 cell will show a dropdown list populated by values within STATE range.

**Note:** Dont forget to clear any existing validation rule before applying. Use Validation.Delete(). I spent countless hours because of this.